# Automatically generated R file

Tags: eclipse, r.java-file

My eclipse project has one glitch and one glitch only which is a line of code in automatically generated R file.

How do I find the associated error be it in layout of my resources or in my values strings? I don't know where the error or disfunction is from in the R file.

Please help and advanced thanks to anyone who answers.

Thanks

Comment: Are you working on Android App ?

Answer (score -1):

Check your eclipse `Problem` or `Marker` tab, which will tell you exactly which xml resource or image have problem.

Answer (score -1):

I have had this issue on many occasions and sometimes the warnings or error markers do no point to any specific issue.

It could be a letter has been typed in a resource file such as strings.xml or incorrect syntax in one of your layout files.

The most thorough approach, and one that I have had to do when I have exhausted other options, is to go over each of your resources that you have edited since it was last working correctly and look for things like a missing semi-colon or an incorrectly placed letter.

Check your resources such as your layout files, your color and string resources. Any of your .xml files could have an issue with them so check them all. More often than not it is something miniscule so don't give up looking.